# Possible? Build on OpenSuse 13.x deploy on SLES 11

Tags: compiling, opensuse, make, suse, sles

I need to build nginx for SLES 11.3
Do I have to build it on the SLES 11.3 Host or could I build it on my local OpenSuse 13.2 Host?

The Problem is that, there are a lot of dependencies missing on the 11.3 for building and the machine is without access to the Internet.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a virtual machine with sles?

Comment: Jupp this was my second option, as I run the OpenSuse as VM and my main Workstation on top of a the crappy Win7 here at work already :-)